# How to patch (mocking) tests with Errbot?

Tags: python, errbot

I'm trying to patch dependencies with my [errbot](http://errbot.io) tests. The problem I'm having is how errbot imports modules. It is not static and breaks my patch decorators as I add tests or they test in a different order.

I have plugin called EDB (edb.py). Inside of edb.py I import pyedb with `import pyedb`. This is located in my `site-packages`.

I have my test file test_edb.py and I try to patch my test methods like this

```
pytest_plugins = ["errbot.backends.test"]
extra_plugin_dir = '.'

from unittest.mock import patch  # noqa: E402

@patch('yapsy_loaded_plugin_EDB_1.pyedb', autospec=True)
def test_edb_testlist(pyedb_mock, testbot):
    testbot.push_message('!edb testlist')

    assert "Okay, let me get..." == testbot.pop_message()
    assert "I don't see any..." == testbot.pop_message()
```

Errbot adds this `yapsy_loaded_plugin_EDB_<xx>` path for module import but the xx depends on the order the test is run. This doesn't work, I need some static import path `mypath.pyedb`.

I'm hoping there is a different way to approach this. Maybe I can change the how I import the module so it's not dependent on errbot imports?

Here is a link to [Errbot testing](http://errbot.io/en/latest/user_guide/plugin_development/testing.html) for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution feels a bit hacky but it works. If anyone has a more elegant solution please share. I'll accept my own answer after awhile if there are no additional responses.

So I've come across this before but I guess I still wasn't familiar enough with how patching works in Python with knowing *where* to patch. After reading the "[Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch)" documentation ( again :) ) I have a work-around given the dynamic imports with errbot.

An errbot project folder will look something

```
errbot-project/
├── data/
│   ├── ...
├── plugins/
│   ├── plugin1/
|       ├── ...
|   ├── plugin2/
|       ├── ...
```

I noticed that when errbot runs both the project directory `../errbot-project` and all the plugin directories (e.g. `../errbot-project/plugins/plugin1`) are added to `sys.path`.

So I added a package to my project directory and I import that in my plugins. I then can patch my dependencies reliably from that package. Again read the [Where to Patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) documentation for full explanation why. It looks something like this.

```
errbot-project/
├── data/
│   ├── ...
├── plugins/
│   ├── plugin1/
|       ├── ...
|   ├── plugin2/
|       ├── ...
├── plugin_deps/
|       ├── __init__.py
```

Where my `../errbot-project/plugin_deps/__init__.py` looks like

```
...
import dep1
import dep2
...
```

And then in my plugin I use

```
...
import plugin_deps as pdep
...
def method():
    pdep.dep1.method()
...
# note, you cannot use 
# from plugin_deps import dep1
# this changes 'where' python looks up the module and
# and 'breaks' your patch
```

And finally my test code looks like

```
@patch('plugin_deps.dep1', autospec=True) 
def test_get_tl_tabulation(my_mock, testbot):
    # test code here
```

Comment: Not sure if this is more elegant, but you may find some useful ideas at https://github.com/coala/corobo/blob/master/tests/labhub_test.py